# How do I enter the Stone Skull?

Tags: steamworld-dig-2

After getting the Booster (and possibly the last Gear Upgrade) if you fly hugging the top of the map of Windy Plains there's a small island with a Stone skull on it.

The map shows it's a cave like the ones found in the temple and mines but when I press up on my controller it wont go in.

So how do I enter this Stone Skull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open the Cave of Trials, find all 42 artifacts and talk to Davy in El Machino to receive the *Sigillum Caelum et Infernum* gear mod.

[image]

After installing the mod, fly to the floating island in Windy Plains. Enter the skull to begin the trial.

[image]

After completing the Cave of Trials, you will unlock:

> The achievement *To Hell and Back* and the *Proof of Completion* artifact.

Sources:

- [Steam Community: 100% Map by Demajen](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1144149252)
- [Steam Community: SteamWorld Dig 2 Steam Achievements by alicewalice](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1216727138)
- [Reddit: Steamworld Dig 2 Endgame](https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/72wzxw/steamworld_dig_2_endgame_spoiler/)
- [Miketendo: A (Fairly) Spoiler Free Insight into what awaits those who 100% Complete SteamWorld Dig 2!](https://miketendo64.com/2017/09/23/feature-a-fairly-spoiler-free-insight-into-what-awaits-those-who-100-complete-steamworld-dig-2/)